# Disable timeout for unit tests in C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, timeout

I'm running into an issue where my tests timeout after 30 minutes. Any ideas on setting infinite timeout? I've tried Timeout(0), but it still throws a timeout after 30 minutes.

I'm running these unit tests in Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: You are going to have to provide more information, like what type of application are you testing for a start.

Comment: You haven't specified what unit test framework you're using or where you're specifying the timeout.

Comment: What are you testing that times out? What testing framework? What is throwing the timeout?

Answer (score 24):

Since 30 minutes is the default timeout for a unit test in the Visual Studio test framework, I'm going to take a guess that this is what you're referring to. If not, please provide more details.

You can set this timeout in at least two ways:

1. Decorate specific `TestMethods` with an attribute: `[Timeout(TestTimeout.Infinite)];` or
2. Using `Test -> Edit Test Settings -> [settings you're using] -> Test Timeouts`.

Note that if you do this using (2), you will have to close and re-open your solution in VS before the change is applied.

Comment: Yep - that's about right :) that's what I was going to suggest.

Comment: I tried both suggestions but couldn't get them to work. I could not find TestTimeout.Infinite so I tried Timeout(Timeout.Infinite) which didn't work. When going through the settings menu, there is no option to set the timeout as infinite (I've tried 00:00:00). The max time I can enter is 23:59:59.

Comment: The TestTimeout enum is found in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting. Perhaps you are missing a "using" / reference?

Comment: As for the settings menu - what version of Visual Studio are you using? I'm using VS2010, and there is a checkbox to completely disable timeouts. See e.g. the description in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256991.aspx.

Comment: First one works for VS2012. Not sure about the second as I didn't find it. +1

Answer (score 4):

It worked for me. You have to add it to the C# test code, just above the test method:

```
[Timeout(TestTimeout.Infinite)]
[TestMethod()]
```